# How can I update a drop down menu using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried using the `val()` method to update a drop down menu using jQuery but for some reason it failed, this is the code:

```js
function doSomething() {
  var company_name = 'micro';
  $("#company").val(company_name);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-left" onclick="doSomething(this);">update</a>
<select id="company" onchange="populateAddress();">
  <option value="apple">apple</option>
  <option value="micro">micro</option>
</select>
```

Comment: where are you calling the funtion ????

Comment: typo: missing `"` here: `onchange="populateAddress();>`

Comment: 1) You don't call the `doSomething()` function anywhere 2) You don't have a method named `populateAddress()` defined in your JS 3) Use unobtrusive event handlers. The `on*` event handlers are very outdated

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I see `doSomething()` getting called onclick of anchor tag

Comment: @anu ah yes you're right, my mistake. Other points are valid though. The code also appears to be working absolutely fine in the snippet. I'd suggest you check the console for errors, OP

Comment: For me the snippet is working fine. On clicking the update link dropdown value is changing properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably by "it failed" to you mean it fails to fire the `onchange` event?  Because `.val()` should definitely work.  Try something like this...

```
$("#company").val(company_name).change();
```

Comment: If you're going to guess at a solution it should probably be a comment. Downvote wasn't me FYI

Comment: Downvote seems harsh, it was just my assessment of the situation and I could only see that as being the problem.  Based on the jQuery documentation, which the user may not have known... `Changing the value of an input element using JavaScript, using .val() for example, won't fire the event.`